# Solspace Tag "Suggestion" dropdown broken

Tags: solspace, solspace-tag

Using Solspace Tag 4.2.5 with EE 2.7.0

The suggestion tool is broken. Triple checked install. De-installed, reinstalled twice...  /themes/ as well as /system/ files.

This is the error: http://cl.ly/U22k

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This solution over at Solspace support would likely fix this:

http://support.solspace.com/solution/categories/115922/folders/236531/articles/145012-how-to-avoid-issues-with-the-tag-custom-field-autocomplete-not

I'll post the answer here for more exposure:

> There may be cases when the Tag custom field's autocomplete does not display any results.
>
> First, please check if the domain in your browser address bar is the same as the domain set in EE. www and non-www domains are not considered the same. Domains need to be the same to prevent AJAX requests (used by Tag) from being considered as Cross-Site Scripting (XSS) attempts, which are blocked by browsers.
>
> One solution is to set up config.php so that EE's site_url changes with the domain used in your browser. You can do this using PHP's $_SERVER variables. Here's an example. You would put this in config.php:
>
> ```
> $protocol              = (isset($_SERVER["HTTPS"]) && $_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") ? "https://" : "http://";
> $base_url              = $protocol . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
> $config['base_url']    = $base_url . '/';
> $config['site_url']    = $config['base_url'];
> $config['cp_url']      = $config['base_url'] . $system_folder . "/index.php";
> ```
>
> This assures that the EE domain for site_url is the same as my browser's domain, every time. This avoids Cross-Site Scripting issues when using AJAX.

Comment: Thanks. Oddly I think it was down to a lack of data. Once I'd added tags to a number of entries Tag started to see them and the suggest tool started working.